# How to trigger React Toastify onClose only after toast closes?

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

The following code renders a toast:

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

export default function App() {
  const notify = () =>
    toast.success("Yabba dabba do", {
      onClose: () => {
        console.log("closing");
      },
      autoClose: 5000
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={notify}>Notify !</button>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, in the console the statement "closing" outputs as soon as the toast renders and again 5 seconds later after the toast closes.  How do I code it so that "closing" only outputs to the console after 5 seconds when the toast closes?  Here's a Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/toast3-forked-pibtut?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it will be solved if you disable stickMode. Not sure if this is what you want.
https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/741

Comment: @QubaishBhatti Bhatti oh that definitely helps!  I was tearing my hair out on this.  Is this a bug in React or in React-Toastify?  Could I fix it by downgrading React-Toastify?  If the problem is in Toastify how many versions back would I have to revert to for it to work?

Comment: You just need to remove stickMode. I just updated your codesandbox. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/toast3-forked-psudoq

Comment: Yes I understand.  I see that taking it out of strictmode fixes it per your suggestion.  Do you think this will eventually be fixed so that we can reenable strictmode?

Comment: As per my understanding its only happening on dev environment. Once you deployed it on any prod environment this issue should not occur.

Comment: This is also happening on useEffect.  (cf https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-use-effect-running-twice/ ) The same kludge-fix can also be applied.